# VS2010から2017に移行した場合のWebサイトのパスについて

Tags: c#, visual-studio, url

VS2010で作成したWeb サイトをVS2017に移行していますが、
デバッグ時に、Webサイト「HogeWeb」のURLが変わってしまいました。

移行前：http://localhost:60357/HogeWeb/Default.aspx
　移行後：http://localhost:60357/Default.aspx

移行後のURLを移行前と同じする方法はありますか？

デバッグ時は、規定Webサーバーを使用しています。
（移行前はASP.NET開発サーバ、移行後はIIS Exress）

Webサイト「HogeWeb」には、プロジェクトファイルはありません。
ソリューションファイルに以下の記述がありますが、移行後には無視されるようです。

```
Project("{XXXXXX}") = "HogeWeb", "HogeWeb\", "{XXXXXX}"
  ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
    TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/HogeWeb"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "HogeWeb\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\HogeWeb\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
    （省略）
    VWDPort = "60357"
  EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

プロジェクトをプロパティページも簡易的な内容で、仮想ディレクトリの作成等は表示されません。

以下の手段を試し一応望んだ結果となったのですが、他の解決方法が知りたいです。
A.Webサイト「HogeWeb」の下に、フォルダ「HogeWeb」を作成しaspxファイルを移動させる。
→物理パスを変えたくないので不可。

B.applicationhost.configに以下（★～★）の記述を追加する。
→元のURLでもアクセスできるため不可。

```
<site name="HogeWeb" id="1">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\user名\source\repos\HogeForm\HogeWeb" />
    </application>
  ★<application path="/HogeWeb" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\user名\source\repos\HogeForm\HogeWeb" />
    </application>★
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:60357:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`<application path="/">`の方の`<virtualDirectory>`に別の物理パスを指定すればよいのでは。

Comment: 別の物理パスにダミーのサイトを用意しておけば動きましたが、
それは避けたいです。

Comment: なぜ避けたいのか分かりませんが、「applicationhost.configはローカルの設定ファイルなので環境依存の構成を含めても問題はない」「指定するディレクトリにWebアプリを配置する必要はない」「IISマネージャーで仮想ディレクトリを設定した場合も同じ記述になる」とは指摘しておきます。